# What is the advised length of time to keep a keep-alive connection (http) open?

Tags: http, http-headers, keep-alive

My question is:

What is the advised length of time to keep a keep-alive connection (http) open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the server you want to keep it as long as you can, since for clients it's always going to be faster to reuse a connection than to open a new one.

However, there are diminishing returns on this — just a couple of seconds will give you fast initial download of the site. Long durations will speed up subsequent navigation only a little.

In typical Apache configurations and other servers that keep thread running per open connection there's a memory cost involved, so it's best to keep it at 2-3 seconds or even disable it and add keep-alive support via haproxy or such.

In evented servers like nginx, lighttpd (and Apache with an experimental event mpm) the cost is relatively small, so you can have long KeepAliveTimeout.

Comment: (So nginx might be a pretty good choice in terms of keep alive connections?)

Answer (score 0):

If you think the "KeepAliveTimeout" value - it depends on your site.If it is something like forum thread with inpage images etc than you could set KeepAliveTimeout to 2 or 3 seconds. If it is very simple page without many inpage images you can stop to use keep-alive. I think it is better to play around with it and run some benchmarks. It is always better :)